# Error: brokencount > 0

Tags: apt, update-manager, dependencies

I am getting the following error in the top menu bar:

```
An error occurred.
Please run the Package Manager from the right-click menu or apt-get in a terminal to see what is wrong.
The error message was:'Error:BrokenCount>0'.
This usually means that your installed packages have unmet dependencies.
```

[image]

How do I solve this problem?

Comment: What happens if you click 'repair' in the dialog?

Comment: Launch gnome-terminal and run sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get upgrade Do you get an error message?

Comment: I tried it but it did not solved

Comment: Did you try `sudo apt-get -f install`?

Comment: Please post the output of `sudo apt-get update && sudo apt-get install -f && sudo dpkg --configure -a`.

Comment: ^ or [Getting the error Error:BrokenCount>0 after installing packages](//askubuntu.com/a/70759)

Answer (score -1):

In the Terminal, type:

```
sudo su
mv  /var/lib/dpkg/status  /var/lib/dpkg/status-bad
cp /var/lib/dpkg/status-old  /var/lib/dpkg/status
mv /var/lib/dpkg/available  /var/lib/dpkg/available-bad
cp /var/lib/dpkg/available-old  /var/lib/dpkg/available
rm -rf /var/lib/dpkg/updates/*
rm -rf /var/lib/apt/lists/*
mkdir /var/lib/apt/lists/partial
rm /var/cache/apt/*.bin
apt-get clean
apt-get autoremove
apt-get update
dpkg --configure -a
apt-get install -f
```

Comment: Can you please post in English and explain what these commands as well? It's really a bad idea to run commands without an explanation.